# How Are Connections Grouped when Pooling?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am using `Npgsql` to connect to a Postgres database on Windows using C#. In the connection string I have:

`Database=dbname;Userid=username;Password=password;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=50;ConnectionLifeTime=300;`

My application has multiple databases. Each database has a user specific to that database. In addition there is one superuser that has access to all databases. It is used to create new databases and the users for them.

What I am seeing is that a database connections are left open per user per database. So when the superuser creates a database it runs a few different queries and then when the last one is done it is left in the idle state and does not get reclaimed. This is causing the total number of connections on the server to be much higher then I would expect.

If I look at `pg_stat_activity` what I would see is (for 2 databases):

```
| user      | database | state  | query                       |
|-----------|----------|--------|-----------------------------|
| db1_user  | db1      | active | SELECT * FROM table         |
| db2_user  | db2      | idle   | SELECT * FROM another_table |
| superuser | db1      | idle   | CREATE USER db1_user        |
| superuser | db2      | idle   | CREATE USER db2_user        |
```

The superuser queries just sit idle forever.

What I am wondering is, is the connection pool per user per database? With the connection string above would each user get a pool of up to 50 connections on each database they connect to? And since `MinPoolSize=1` will each user have an idle connection on each database they connect to?

Comment: It depends on the ADO.NET provider you are using to connect to postgresql. What library are you using, you tagged your question `npgsql` is that what you are using?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes I am using `npgsql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's keyed on the connection string itself. For most uses this makes good sense; one generally has a small number of connection strings in use (often just one or maybe two) and that string is used lots.

For the sort of use here, it would likely make more sense not to use pooling for the user strings at all, just the superuser string that has greater reuse.

Comment: OK that makes sense. So using my example above the connections would be pooled by keying on `dbname`, `username` and `password` correct?

The other question I have is, how come the superuser queries never get cleaned up? They stay there over the 5 minutes specified in the `ConnectionLifeTime`